# Why is it legal in C++ to call a constructor of a primitive type?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

Why is the following code legal in C++?

```
bool a(false);
```

I mean, the `T a(VALUE)` should call constructor, right? I suppose it's not parsed as function declaration. But `bool` is plain type, it doesn't have constructor. Or does it?

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 if it's relevant.

Comment: It is legal because the designers of the language said so. What would be a good reason to make it illegal?

Comment: `int x(5)` is allowed as well. The "constructor" is just a no-op, if we want.

Comment: why plain types cannot have constructors?

Comment: I guess it isn't any different from `int x(5)`, it's just that I never saw this syntax before. All I knew was `bool a { false };` and `bool a = false;`. So I was just curious..

Comment: @CoryKramer I suspect it is just an example. It could have been `int a(5)` or `double x(3.14);`.

Comment: @Paladin `bool a { false };` is the same as `bool a(false);` {} form was not available before c++11

Comment: It is worth noting that `bool a{false};` is OK for a data member declaration, but `bool a(false);` isn't allowed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is just a valid syntax to initialize POD types and have a similar behavior to a constructor (or even a copy constructor for that matter).

For example, the following would be valid:

```
bool a(false);
bool b(a);
bool c = bool(); // initializes to false
```

One interesting thing to note is that in

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
  bool f();
  return 0;
}
```

`f` is a function declaration!

Comment: `bool c = bool(); // initializes to false` Are you sure?

Comment: @user3528438, yes, after that statement, `c` would be a `bool` with `false` as value.

Comment: Interesting, I thought `bool c = bool();` is equivalent to `bool c;` and would give `c` a indeterminate value if `c` is not static storage duration.

Answer (score 29):

Although `bool` is a primitive type, and as such has no constructor, language designers introduced unified initialization syntax that works for primitives as well as for classes. This greatly simplifies writing template code, because you can continue using the

```
T tVar(initialVal);
```

syntax without knowing if `T`, a template type parameter, is primitive or not. This is a very significant benefit to template designers, because they no longer need to think about template type parameters in terms of primitive vs. classes.

Comment: This should be accepted as an answer. I really like this answer because it explains the real reason behind this syntax. Bjarne Stroustrup also says exactly like this in his book "The C++ Programming language" Section 6.2.8. +5

Comment: Upvoted. now it has voted 2x more than the accepted answer. Hop you get gold badge now. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

This is no different than any other primitive type, e.g.

```
int a(5);
```

Primitive types have no constructors, what you are invoking is [*direct-initialization*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)

Comment: That doesn't look like value initialization.

Comment: I think you mean direct initialization.

Comment: You are both correct. One day I'll get the right name without having to double-check cppreference!