# Default initializing a pointer in a template

Tags: c++, templates

In the following code, `Get()` returns the default value of the template type. I was wondering why and how this is correct/defined for pointer types

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <typename ValueType>
inline ValueType Get()
{
   return ValueType();   
}

int main()
{
   int* IntPtr = Get<int*>();
   //int* IntPtr2 = (int*)(); // Invalid
   //int* IntPtr3 = (int*){}; // Valid
   
   std::cout << (IntPtr == nullptr ? "nullptr" : "non-nullptr") << std::endl;
   
   std::cin.get();
   
   return 0;
}
```

When the compiler evaluates `ValueType()` in `Get`, I would have expected it to become `(int*)()`, but since this is invalid, is it treated differently?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747665/4117728

Comment: that answer seems to be relevant, but i still don't get why in main `int* x = (int*)(123)` is fine while `int* x = (int*)();` is not

Comment: @idclev463035818 Templates have different parsing rules, in particular, the semantic meaning of a dependent expression is fixed regardless of the type. `ValueType()` is parsed as a default initialized `ValueType`. `(int*)()` is always not.

Comment: @idclev463035818 I may be wrong here but maybe it's because it has a value, it creates a pointer pointing to 123 address, wherever that is :), but since `int*` has no direct initialization it's invalid whereas `(int*){}` works because of the initializer-list, if you use `(int)()` instead of `(int*)()`, it works fine precisely because of said direct-initialization.

Comment: @anastaciu I can follow you, but what exactly makes it different inside the template? I know it is parsed differently, but what exactly is it?

Comment: @idclev463035818, well that is question, PasserBy hints to something but I don't know why.

Comment: should this get the `language-lawyer` tag?

Comment: @idclev463035818, I reckon it seems fitting.

Comment: @anastaciu I was about to add it but better leave it to OP, language-lawyer question are treated a little different and Im not sure if thats what OP wants

Comment: @Bas in het Veld, try this:
   `typedef int* pint; 
   int* IntPtr2 = pint(); // valid`

Comment: @B0FEE664 I'm not really trying to get anything working, I just realized I didn't understand what happens here, that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: @Bas in het Veld, it was a hint. :) Informally speaking, any named type can be initialized with the syntax  `type_name()`, but not with the syntax `(type_name)()`, because the second one it a type cast or function call (or samething else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *When the compiler evaluates `ValueType()` in `Get`, I would have expected it to become `(int*)()`, but since this is invalid, is it treated differently?*

A C++ template, while being very similar to a macro, does not perform a literal replacement. `ValueType` remains an actual type within the scope of the template. So yes, `return ValueType()` would be treated differently from `(int*)()`, more like `using ValueType = int*; return ValueType();`

As to why `using ValueType = int*; ValueType();` works when `(int*)()` doesn't:

In C++, an expression of the form `T()` (when `T` is a type) is [*value-initialization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) syntax which creates a nameless object of type `T`.

During *value-initialization*, non-class types are [*zero-initialized*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization).

The problem is `(int*)()` does not have the form `T()`, but `(T)()`. `(int*)()` is parsed as a cast to `int*`, but then it's missing the value to cast. Which is exactly what the compiler says in the error:

```
<source>:2:27: error: expected expression
    int* IntPtr2 = (int*)();
                          ^
```

For the same reason `using T = int; int x = (T)();` also won't compile.

Similarly `int* IntPtr3 = (int*){};` is also invalid C++ (GCC compiles it, but e.g. MSVC won't).

Some possible workarounds:

1. `typedef` the pointer to some type, then you'll be able to use the `T()` form normally:

   ```
    using T = int*;
    T ptr = T();
   ```
2. Use copy-list-initialization syntax:

   ```
    int* ptr = {};
   ```
3. Use direct-list-initialization syntax:

   ```
    int* ptr{};
   ```

Note that the direct-initialization form `int* ptr();` is also unusable as it is subject to most vexing parse.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense, the syntax being that of a cast is what I was missing! Exactly what I was looking for!