# int OR int() for initialization to zero in C++

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

A confusion regarding the concept of using parenthesis '**( )**' in C++.

I found out when we use **int()** it means, we are calling constructor of "**int**" data type. And in C++, int() initializes whatever variable with the default value of **0**.

Is this correct way to initialize my variable to value '0'?

```
int() var;
```

apart from typical way of initialization like:

```
int var = 0;
```

Comment: `int() var;` doesn't compile, so no, it is not the correct way.

Comment: Take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31747645/4165552

Comment: Ignoring vexing parse, it would be `int var();` (but it is a function declaration). so `auto var = int();` or `int var{};`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: They do, just as much as any other datatype with trivial initialization.  Which is to say, no "constructor function" exists, but the syntax may still be used.

Comment: I'd use `auto var{0};`

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, but the most basic seem to be:

Uniform initialization syntax:

```
int var{};
```

This is typically used for members of structs and classes.

Basic C style:

```
int var = 0;
```

Typically used for local variables.

The preferred way is a matter of style, so it is up to you to define your own style guide and follow it.

For example, Google C++ style guide allows multiple syntax variants:
https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Variable_and_Array_Initialization

but it would be confusing if different syntaxes are used in a short piece of code. Typically people try to stick to one particular style in a file/folder/library.